# Java Selenium - JavaScriptExecutor - Argument is of an illegal type: driverFactory.CustomWebElement

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a CustomWebDriver class which implements JavascriptExecutor and I have the override as below:

```
@Override
public Object executeScript(String script, Object... args) {
    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, args);
}
```

When I use this as below, I see an the error: `Argument is of an illegal type: driverFactory.CustomWebElement`

```
    WebElement testElmtBy = returnSearchLists().get(i);
    WebDriver vDriver = driver.get();
   ((JavascriptExecutor)vDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", testElmtBy);
```

`returnSearchLists().get(i)` is of `CustomWebElement` type and in that class the element is `public WebElement iElement;`

Though I declared testElmtBy as WebElement, it is still being considered as CustomWebElement.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the below solution for this issue:

I had `CustomWebElement` implement `WrapsElement` and have the override as below:

```
public WebElement iElement;    
@Override
public WebElement getWrappedElement() {
    return iElement;
}
```